# Дополнить кодировку с Windows 10 для Windows XP

Tags: windows, delphi, кодировка

Доброе время суток форумчане
Сделал для моей программы свои кнопки для набора символов.
В Windows ХP (слева) кодировка «хромает»., в Windows 10 (справа) все ok
Как решить проблему?

P.S.
Например карточный знак "пика", в Windows XP, Microsoft Word отображает, а в программе это квадратик

Заранее спасибо за ответ [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, проблема со шрифтом и во времена WinXP в шрифте просто не было этих знаков. Например, [знак российского рубля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F) был утверждён в 2013 году и если шрифт с того времени не обновлялся, то и отобразить его нету никаких шансов. Вернее, шанс есть только с новыми/обновлёнными шрифтами.

Comment: так может windows XP дополнить кодировкой? про знак "пика", я уже писал.

Comment: Шрифтом, а не кодировкой. И шрифт должен поддерживать современную версию юникода. Ну и в программе вам надо указать, чтобы она использовала этот шрифт, а не произвольный системный.

Comment: Вот о чём я говорю: [Поддержка нового символа российского рубля — Microsoft Office](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F-%E2%80%94-microsoft-office-25b7c7df-ea17-4c1e-aefd-158f2cafbc89)

Comment: ща, изменил шрифт, с "Tahoma" "Times New Roman" некоторые символы начали появляться, посмотрим...

Comment: Как мне Подсказали, шрифт "**Lucida Sans Unicode**", отобразил правильность симолов, где-то на 83% кнопок. В общем например символ с кодом "9731", так и не удалось отобразить

Comment: Ну да, задача сводится к поиску нужного шрифта. Посмотрите, какие шрифты используются в современных линуксах, возможно один из них подойдёт. Ещё можете попробовать взять рабочий шрифт из Win10 и установить его в XP. Но только на свой страх и риск.

Comment: @zed, а разве формат шрифтов менялся?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не могу точно сказать, не в курсе. Поэтому и предупреждаю.

Answer (score 1):

Это не кодировка хромает, а там в шрифте нужных символов просто нет.

Берёшь с собой нужный шрифт, кладёшь рядом с программой, загружаешь и отображаешь текст им. Для временной регистрации шрифта в системе в winapi имеется пара функций (забыл, какие именно), причём их можно использовать даже без админских прав.

Если же у программы есть инсталлятор, то можно установить соответствующий шрифт в систему.

Comment: Только не забудьте, что у шрифтов тоже есть лицензии.